# Why am I receiving a different play button shape in ipad air than in desktop?

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, audio

So here's the shape I receive (there is supposed to be only a play button not another triangular play shape above it). Any idea why this happens when I browse it in ipad air?

[image]

And this is what I should receive (say in desktop):
[image]

Here's the code I've used:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    /*Place Your Javascript Below This Line*/
    var aud = document.getElementById('audio2');
    this.questionclick = function(event,element){

        if((element.type == "button") && (element.name == "play"))
        {
            aud.play();
            // remove the element
            element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
            // or set it to disabled, what you like
            element.disabled = true;
        }

    }


});
```

and HTML is:

```
Now that you know how the auditory stories will sound, you are ready to listen to and comprehend the two auditory stories in this study. The first auditory story is titled, &ldquo;The Honey Gatherer&rsquo;s Three Sons.&rdquo; Press the &ldquo;Play Story&rdquo; button to begin listening to the story; after you have finished listening to the story, you will answer a set of questions about the story.
<div>&nbsp;
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<audio controls="controls" id="audio2" preload="preload" style="display:none"><source src="http://langcomplab.net/Honey_Gatherers_Master.webm" style="width:50%" type="audio/webm" /> <source src="http://langcomplab.net/Honey_Gatherers_Master.mp3" style="width:50%" type="audio/mpeg" /><source src="http://langcomplab.net/Honey_Gatherers_Master.ogg" style="width:50%" type="audio/ogg" /> Your browser doesn&#39;t support this audio format.</audio>
</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div><button name="play" style="height:25px; width:200px" type="button">Play Story</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this :
***If you want to provide your own media controller on the desktop or iPad, just leave out the controls attribute.***

Source : [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Introduction/Introduction.html)

However I don't find it a good method to leave out controls as I need it that feature in the first place for fall back message purpose.